# do browsers protect users IP address?

Tags: php, mysql, web

I am writing code in PHP, and I would like to detect the client's IP address.
I have been using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].

It works usually... But sometimes I get the address 127.255.255.255, when clearly a user which was on a regular internet connection tried to connect the website. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: what web server are you running?

Comment: No
http://haveamint.com/forum/troubleshooting/878/heavy_presence_of_127_255_255_255

Comment: I am actually not sure, I am using webhubhosting.com.

Comment: You should check with them if they're using a proxy or something and why could you be getting a broadcast address (127.255.255.255) as the remote address of the client. As another user here said, the REMOTE_ADDR variable is set by the webserver which runs your PHP script using the IP address from which it's receiving the request.

Answer (score 3):

`127.255.255.255` is a broadcast from you internal server (loopback)

If your sure it's an external user, you should check for [code injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) possibilities on your site.

Comment: but why would it work for some addresses and for others it doesn't? that's strange.

Comment: Do you have any RewriteRules in you `.htaccess` file using the `[P]` flag? You might be proxying some pages yourselves?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not where you are looking for. In fact, when you store `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` in mysql using `inet_aton`, you must make sure that the column is defined as `int (11) unsigned`.

If your column is a signed `int`, then the data gets truncated, and all IP addresses larger than 127.255.255.255 are saved as such.

You need to run this query on your mysql table (change the table and column name):

```
ALTER TABLE  `stats` CHANGE `ip` `ip` INT( 11 ) UNSIGNED;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ip2long will return a number as large as 4294967295 (for 255.255.255.255) and that your INT MySQL field (if signed), accept a max value of 2147483647 (source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html ) and will so any value higher than 2147483647 will be stored as 2147483647. This is why you have a lot of 127.255.255.255 in your database.

I guess that converting your database column to BIGINT or unsigned INT will fix that, but be aware that some implementations (I think it's 32-bit vs 64-bit) of ip2long() will return a negative number, to be careful.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title:
REMOTE_ADDR is set by the corresponding webserver and cannot be modified by the User (except by using Proxies etc.). It is determined from the incoming TCP connection before any HTTP takes place.

However, it might be obfuscated by some firewalls or proxies in the server's network.

Additionally confusing is that 127.255.255.255 is a broadcast address and should not be a source for an HTTP connection (which is TCP, which is Unicast only).