# Why am I getting the IP from the server as 127.255.255.255, this is not a valid IP for a user

Tags: php, mysql, ip, cloudflare

I don't think this is anyone spoofing an IP, I think this is something wrong on my end causing a lot of IP's to appear as `127.255.255.255`.

I am using Cloudflare and here is the code I am using:

```
if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"]))
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP"];
if($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != "::1" && $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != NULL)
    $ip = ip2long($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Am I doing something wrong here to get such weird IP's?

Comment: Is this before MySQL? Or are you perhaps using a 32bit signed table column to store it? `long2ip((1<<31)-1)`

Comment: @mario this is my SQL for the ip CHANGE  `ip`  `ip` INT( 11 ) NULL DEFAULT NULL

Comment: Yes, a signed `INT` is too short.

Comment: @mario should I change it to a "BIGINT" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [do browsers protect users IP address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655215/do-browsers-protect-users-ip-address)